# Cookie not being saved (Angular, Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

Cookie received in chrome dev tools > network > cookies but not appearing in application > cookies

I have a login function that sets a cookie when a user logs in. It is appearing in the cookies column under the network tab but not in the application tab.

this is the function in express handling the cookie setting. This function is called when there is a post request made to the `/login/` route.

```
const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  const dbRes = await authenticateUser(req.body);

  if (dbRes.authenticated) {
    res.setHeader(
      "set-cookie",
      `session=${dbRes.cookie}; 
path=/; samesite=lax`
    );
    // I've also tried using res.cookie()
    res.status(200).json({ status: "authenticated" });
  } else if (dbRes.authenticated === false) {
    res.status(401).json({ status: "wrong username, email or password" });
  } else {
    res.status(dbRes.status).json({ error: dbRes.error });
  }
};
```

Cookie setting works as expected when i do it like this and i go to the `/cookie/` route in browser.

```
app.use("/cookie/", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("set-cookie", "foo=bar");
  res.send("set");
});
```

I have an angular frontend sending a post request to `/login/` route but the login route is undefined in my angular app so the user will be redirected to `/` route.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UserLoggedInGuard } from './guards/user-logged-in.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/login/login.module').then((m) => m.LoginModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'feed',
    loadChildren: () => import('./feed/feed.module').then((m) => m.FeedModule),
    canActivate: [UserLoggedInGuard],
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

However, the `/cookie/` route set by express is not redirected and the cookie is being set correctly. I'm wondering if there are any conflicts between the angular and express router making setting cookies problematic.

I need help understanding why the cookie is not appearing in the application tab although it was received by the browser under the network tab.

--

As per Kavinda's answer, I tried adding `useCredentials` to my frontend code like so

```
loginUser(data: LoginForm) {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.domainLink}/login`, data, {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }
```

Unfortunately, this fix isnt working for me either even after setting credentials to true in the backend.

--

I've resorted to using ngx-cookie in Angular to set the cookie for now instead. However, I'd still appreciate it if someone can explain what I'm doing wrong here in the backend. Thanks!

I'll include my current workaround below in hopes it will help someone too
login.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { CookieModule } from 'ngx-cookie';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LoginRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CookieModule.withOptions(),
  ],
  providers: [CookieService],
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

login.component.ts (res is the response from server where i returned a json value with the cookie value stored in the `cookie` key.

`this.cookieService.put('session', res.cookie);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem. I was running on the domain 'localhost' but my request link was going to '127.0.0.1' instead. Cookies cannot be set from a different domain.

Not setting the withCredentials flag to true originally didn't help my case either.

Answer (score 1):

After testing it out it appears that chrome (86.0.4240.198) still allows cross site cookies on localhost which means that your problem is not caused by the new restrictions and using `{ useCredentials: true }` should work fine.

Comment: I assume you mean like this?

loginUser(data: LoginForm) {
    return this.httpClient.post(\`${this.domainLink}/login\`, data, {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }

If so, it still isnt working for me unfortunately.